# SQL temp table already exists even though I checked it with OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##myTable') IS NULL

Tags: sql-server

I need to use existing global temp tables or create them and fill if they don't exist.

Example of one table

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##myTable') IS NULL
begin
    create table ##myTable (
        --stuff
    )
end
COMMIT TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRANSACTION
if (select count(*) from ##myTable) = 0
begin
    insert into ##myTable
    --select stuff
end
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Sometimes it works and sometimes error "Table ##myTable already exists" shows. I am the only one who uses those global temp tables

Comment: You're never dropping the table. Personally I would always do the inverse to what you have done, Check if the table exists and if so drop it. Then create it straight after. Also, is there any need to two transactions here?

Comment: That is the thing - I don't want to drop tables. If table already exists I want to use it in the select statement. If it doesn't then I want to create it, fill it and then use it in the select statement.

Comment: its seems good ..there is nothing wrong

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic race condition. Multiple sessions can execute the `if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##myTable') IS NULL` query at the same time. If the table doesn't exist, both will attempt to create the table and only one will succeed.

One way to address the issue is with an [application lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql) to serialize the code block among multiple sessions. For example:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON; --best practice with explict T-SQL transactions
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
EXEC sp_getapplock 
      @Resource = 'create ##myTable'  
     ,@LockMode = 'Exclusive'   
     ,@LockOwner = 'Transaction';
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##myTable') IS NULL
begin
    create table ##myTable (
        --select stuff
    );
end;
COMMIT TRANSACTION; --also releases app lock
```

Comment: is @Resource should be exactly 'create ##myTable' and not 'create table ##myTable' or '##myTable' ?

Comment: @Slyzor, the resource name can be any string up to 255 characters so you can specify a more verbose value if you prefer. The requirement is only that it uniquely identify the semaphore resource. The first 32 characters are returned by system DMVs and procs so you might want to keep it under that size to facilitate troubleshooting.

Comment: @Slyzor, mark this as the answer for visibility to others with the same question.